# About the group generated by one diagonal unitary

Tags: matrix-analysis, unitary-representations

Suppose $D=diag\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\alpha_n\}$ is a diagonal unitary, which means that |\alpha_i|=1 for all $i$. We know that $\alpha_i$ is not unit root and so is $\alpha_i/\alpha_j$ for $i\neq j$.

Set $O=\{D,D^2,...,D^k,....\}$, how to describe $O$? Is it dense in diagonal unitaries?

Comment: Yes, it is dense by a fairly standard argument, probably dating back to Blichfeldt.

Comment: @Robinson Thanks a lot, and could you please give me a reference?

Comment: Multidimensional Kroneker theorem (Theorem 443 in Hardy Wright, an introduction to the theory of numbers). But, using additive notations ($\alpha_i=e^{2\pi ix_i}$), the needed hypotheses are stronger: linear independence of $1,x_1,\dots,x_n$ over the rationals. $x_i$ irrationals with irrational differences is not enough, consider $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ (taking multiples, the fractional part of the third component is always in one of two linear relations with the first two)

Comment: @user46855, Here, we only consider unitary, so your example does not fit this.

Comment: I think linear independence over the rationals of the logarithms of the eigenvalues is probably necessary, as user46855 indicates.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson Thanks.

Comment: @user46855 Thanks. I was wrong.